# C++ Constructor/Destructor invocation & Does calling "new" on dynamically created data delete the old data?

Tags: c++

In C++, does calling `new` on a pointer that holds `new`'d data delete the old data?

I want to say that it doesn't, and that it would cause a leak. Calling new on a pointer that already contains data would surely just point the pointer to the new data and we would lose the reference to the old data?

I ask because I was looking at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/15396/), and I notice in the constructors it has been suggested that the OP does this:

```
MyString::MyString()
{
     // A new, empty string contains zero characters plus a terminating zero.
     nlength = 1;
     nstring = new char[1];
     nstring[0] = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString(const char *input)
{
     // A new, copy of a C-string contains exactly the same number of characters in
     // the C-string plus a terminating zero.
     nlength = strlen( input ) + 1;
     nstring = new char[ nlength ];
     strcpy(nstring, input);
}

MyString::MyString(const MyString& S)
{
     nlength = S.nlength;  // we know this is correct!
     nstring = new char[ nlength ];
     strcpy( nstring, S.nstring );
}

//nstring is deleted in the destructor
MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete[] nstring;
}
```

This seems strange to me. As, if `nstring` has already been defined then it would leak? no?

However, these are constructors, so I guess the logic here is that they will only be called once per instance. That makes sense. However, what would happen if I did the following:

```
MyString myString("test");
myString = MyString("test2"); //is the destructor invoked here?
```

If the destructor is invoked upon reassigning myString then it all makes sense to me.

So in summary, 2 things I would like confirmed:

- if you assign `new` data to a pointer that already had `new` data, then this will leak, correct?
- when reassigning objects, is the object's destructor invoked?

Comment: 1) correct.  it would leak.   2) in the above example, where you ask is the destructor invoked, the answer is yes.  But You really should be testing this yourself.  It's easy enough to create a simple console app, with cout/printf in the constructor/destructor and assignment and copy constructor to see what it actually does.

Comment: @zumalifeguard ack, I've been testing various things with this, and for some reason I didn't think to actually test the destructor. I will do that now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I think the insightful answer to "Is the destructor invoked here" is "Yes - but probably not the one that you're thinking of"  The MyString on the right side of the equals sign's destructor runs.  The myString on the left side of the equal sign has its assignment operator invoked.

Comment: Note that this is being done in constructors which are responsible for setting up the data members - not ordinary member functions where the data members should have already been validly set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the pointer behavior: the memory will not be released when the pointer is reassigned.

The issue with your code (I changed the name of the variable to avoid confusion):

```
MyString x("test");
x = MyString("test2");
```

is that the second line does not call the constructor or destructor of `x` again. In C++, constructors and destructors are called just once per object. This code calls **the assignment operator**.

The sequence call would be:

1. Call the constructor of `x` with `"test"`.
2. Call the constructor of the unnamed temporary with `"test2"`.
3. Call the assignment operator of `x` with the temporary object.
4. Call the destructor of the temporary object.
5. At the end of the current scope, call the destructor of `x`.

The assignment operator should be defined more or less this way:

```
const MyString &MyString::operator=(const MyString&o)
{
    nlength = S.nlength;  // we know this is correct!
    delete []nstring;
    nstring = new char[ nlength ];
    strcpy( nstring, S.nstring );
    return *this;
}
```

Naturally this code is not exception safe. What will happen if this `new` fails? The object will be broken! So do instead:

```
const MyString &MyString::operator=(MyString o)
{
    swap(*this, o);
    return *this;
}
```

This is called the copy-n-swap idiom, or something like that. The sequence of calls with this `operator=` when running the point 3 above would be:

1. Call the copy constructor of `o` passing in the temporary.
2. Swap the values of `o` and `this`.
3. Calling the destructor of `o`, that will delete the first allocation (`"test1"`).

Comment: Great answer. And thanks for providing further information regarding the "copy-n-swap (or something like that :P)" idiom.

Answer (score 2):

No, any pointer returned via a call to `new` or `new[]` must be free'd with a corresponding call to `delete` or `delete[]`.

```
int* x = new int;
x = new int; // Memory leak!
```

In C++ `new` is an operator which returns an object allocated on the heap.  It doesn't care what you assign it to.  The only thing that matters is that the object returned via `new` is eventually passed to the `delete` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is called before any other member function. Therefore it is not possible that  `nstring` already points to some allocated memory.

As you say, `x = new int;` does not `delete` whatever `x` was pointing to before (if anything).

The line: `myString = MyString("test2");` calls `myString.operator=( MyString("test2") );`. You speak as if you thought it destroyed `MyString` and then constructed a new one, but that is not happening. It is just a function which we call the copy-assignment operator, and you should implement this function.

There is a construction and destruction involved in the expression `MyString("test2")`, but that does not affect `myString`.

Answer (score 1):

`In C++, does calling new on a pointer that holds new'd data delete the old data?`

No.  You must `delete` the allocated memory.

`If the destructor is invoked upon reassigning myString then it all makes sense to me.`

```
MyString myString("test");
myString = MyString("test2"); //is the destructor invoked here?
```

The code you posted is interesting.  There is an assignment done, in addition to a construction.  The issue with your class is that it lacks a user-defined assignment operator (at least it wasn't shown), so there *is* a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`new` does not deallocate pre-allocated memory. You *will* get a memory leak if you use `new` before deallocating the resource. In your example, doing `myString = MyString("test2")` does indeed cause a memory leak as the copy-assignment operator (or move-asssignment depending on the compiler version) doesn't go to lengths to clean up the memory already held by `nstring`. Both of these functions are provided by the compiler as you haven't created them yourself, and their job (by default) is simply to copy (or move) member-wise, without regard to memory management.